# Promise Error not getting propagated

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

My code is like this,

```
function promisefn1() {
  return someFunction.then(function(data) {
    //here i check some thing and throw an error
    if (someConditions) {
      throw new Error('some error');
    }
    return someOtherFunction();
  });
}

function test() {
  return bluebird.props({
    attribute1: promisefn1(),
    attribute2: promisefn2()
  })
}
```

In the above code, if the error is thrown from promisefn1 the callee function test is not getting rejected. If I add an error handler in bluebird.props  I get the error there. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you handler was called? If `someFunction` is a function you should call it `return someFunction().then`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i edited the code. When i changed code like this function test() {
  return bluebird.props({
    attribute1: promisefn1(),
    attribute2: promisefn2()
  }).then(null , function(e) {
    console.log("error", e);
    return;
  })
} 
This logged error. If i remove the handler the test function never get resolver

Comment: could you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue. The code works for me https://jsfiddle.net/nf9t9w3b/

Comment: @YuryTarabanko https://jsfiddle.net/amithh/e3m09pk5/